# Check if Scala class is instance of T

Tags: scala, generics

My application handles a lot of third party integrations. I have an abstract base class for third party integrations which specifies a bunch of methods that an integration class should handle – then certain integrations can be extended with additional functionality that is not available on all integrations.

Basically it looks like this:

```
abstract class Integration { ... }
trait SingleSignOn { ... }

class NormalIntegration extends Integration {}
class SingleSignOnIntegration extends Integration with SingleSignOn {}
```

I would like to be able to sort out all integrations that have a specific trait, and this is what I thought of as the basic solution:

```
val allIntegrations: Seq[Integration] = ...

def integrationsWithTrait[T]: Seq[Integration] = {
  allIntegrations.filter(_.isInstanceOf[T])
}
```

The usage is:

```
val singleSignOnIntegrations = integrationsWithTrait[SingleSignOn]
```

The issue is that `isInstanceOf[T]` always returns true (meaning I end up with `singleSignOnIntegrations == allIntegrations`), while hard coded `isInstanceOf[SingleSignOn]` works as intended.

How do I fix `integrationsWithTrait` to work as I intend?

Comment: certainly `isInstanceOf[T]` gave a compiler warning...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
def integrationsWithTrait[T](implicit tag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): Seq[Integration] = {
  allIntegrations.filter(tag.runtimeClass.isInstance)
}
```

Scalac will inject `ClassTag` instance for every class that this method will be called with. This will allow to access the `Class` object in runtime and verify if the class is the instance of given class/trait.

I think the original code doesn't work because of type erasure.